# C# Custom Comparer with Comparison delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, comparison

I'm trying to sort a custom BindingList. But i came across the problem that my Comparer does not recognize the properties of my class.
The "x.Code_PK_OriginalValue" is not recognized. The weird thing is that intellisense marks "Begrenzingen" in Comparer class different as "Begrenzingen" in the first code block beneath.

```
BindingListX<Begrenzingen> lst = new BindingListX<Begr.....;

lst.OrderBy(t => t, new CustomComparer<Begrenzingen>());
```

.

```
public class CustomComparer<Begrenzingen> : IComparer<Begrenzingen>
{
    private readonly Comparison<Begrenzingen> _comparison;

    public CustomComparer()
    {
        _comparison = new Comparison<Begrenzingen>(
                            (Begrenzingen x, Begrenzingen y) =>
                            {
                                return x.Code_PK_OriginalValue.CompareTo(y.Code_PK_OriginalValue);
                            }
                      );
    }

    public int Compare(Begrenzingen x, Begrenzingen y)
    {
        return _comparison(x, y);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class BindingListX<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    public void OrderBy(Func<T,T> keySelector, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        this.Items.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Begrenzingen : DefaultTable, IComparable<Begrenzingen>
{
    public Begrenzingen()
    { //New -> Insert DB
        Code_PK_OriginalValue = -1;
        isDeleted = false;
    }

    public decimal Code_PK_OriginalValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Code_PK { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public decimal? SeqLayer { get; set; }

    public Boolean isDeleted { get; set; }

    public string SeqLayerDisplayValue { 
        get {
            if (SeqLayer == null) return string.Empty;
            return (from sdo in MainWindow.Main.SdoLayers where sdo.SeqLayer == this.SeqLayer select sdo.DisplayValue).First();
        } 
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}", Code_PK_OriginalValue, Code_PK, Naam, SeqLayer);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Begrenzingen o)
    {
        return Code_PK.CompareTo(o.Code_PK);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your class look like?

Comment: Why are you using a extra comparison instead of implementing the logic inside of the `Compare` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just `lst.OrderBy(t => t.Code_PK_OriginalValue);`

Comment: I changed my code to
`public void OrderBy(Func<T, decimal> keySelector)
        {
            this.Items.OrderBy(keySelector);
        }`

and `lst.OrderBy(t => t.Code_PK);`.
But this does not get my list sorted. The items are stil in the original order.

Comment: `OrderBy` doesnt actually sort the list but returns an sorted `IEnumerable` Use: `lst = lst.OrderBy(t => t.Code_PK).ToList();`